# Invoking timeout in aframe application during runtime

Tags: aframe

I am a Masters student working on developing an A-frame based VR application for my project
and synchronizing its performance for multiple users in heterogeneous network conditions. Does anyone have any idea how can I invoke an asset timeout during runtime for any user who has a slower network connection with a latency of say more than 30ms. So basically if the latency is above 30ms, I want the asset timeout to be invoked so that the VR rendering can start.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [a-assets timeout attribute](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/core/asset-management-system.html#events_timeout)

```
<a-assets src="model.gltf" timeout="30">
  ...
</a-assets>
```

Consider that 30ms is not much time when fetching assets over the network.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Diego. I just have one more question, Can the a-frame application be deployed to an edge distribution server say AWS cloudfront for better performance?

Comment: I don’t have a concrete answer but there’s nothing specific to A-Frame on that regard. Practices for regular sites will also apply to A-Frame

Comment: If you can flag answer as correct it will be appreciated